# Trouble with UI elements following touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In a iOS app I have two UI elements that follow the users touch. The problem is that if the touch moves to fast, the UI elements stop following. 
(It also makes sure that the UI elements cannot move outside certain bounds)

Here is the code I am using to move the UI elements around, running on touches moved:

```
// Move the pinch UI around
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint imageHeight = CGPointMake((_pinchUI_top.frame.origin.x)+(_pinchUI_top.frame.size.width/2), size_OriginalImage.height);

    // Top line
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_pinchUI_top frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])) {

        CGPoint touchLocY = CGPointMake((_pinchUI_top.frame.origin.x)+(_pinchUI_top.frame.size.width/2), touchLoc.y);
        _pinchUI_top.center = touchLocY;

        // If outside of image, stop
        if (touchLocY.y > imageHeight.y) {
            _pinchUI_top.center = imageHeight;
        }
        else {
            pixelsFromBottom = touchLoc.y;
        }

    // Bottom line
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint([_pinchUI_bottom frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])) {

        CGPoint touchLocY = CGPointMake((_pinchUI_bottom.frame.origin.x)+(_pinchUI_bottom.frame.size.width/2), touchLoc.y);
        _pinchUI_bottom.center = touchLocY;

        // If outside of image, stop
        if (touchLocY.y > imageHeight.y) {
            _pinchUI_bottom.center = imageHeight;
        }
        else {
            pixelsFromTop = touchLoc.y;
        }
    }
}
```

`_pinchUI_top` and `_pinchUI_bottom` are the two UI elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the touchesBegan event to get the original positions (and handle top or bottom), so instead of checking this in the touchesMoved, do it when the touch event starts. Then in the touchesMoved event you can move the appropriate image.

```
float topY;
float bottomY;
bool touchValid;
bool touchTop;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    float touchY = touchLoc.y;

    touchValid = NO;

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_pinchUI_top frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])) {
        topY = touchY;
        touchTop = YES;
        touchValid = YES;
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint([_pinchUI_bottom frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])){
        bottomY = touchY;
        touchTop = NO;
        touchValid = YES;
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint imageHeight = CGPointMake((_pinchUI_top.frame.origin.x)+(_pinchUI_top.frame.size.width/2), size_OriginalImage.height);

    if (touchValid) {

        // Top line
        if (touchTop) {

            CGPoint touchLocY = CGPointMake((_pinchUI_top.frame.origin.x)+(_pinchUI_top.frame.size.width/2), touchLoc.y);
            _pinchUI_top.center = touchLocY;

            // If outside of image, stop
            if (touchLocY.y > imageHeight.y) {
            _pinchUI_top.center = imageHeight;
            }
            else {
                pixelsFromBottom = touchLoc.y;
            }

    // Bottom line
        } else if (!touchTop) {

            CGPoint touchLocY = CGPointMake((_pinchUI_bottom.frame.origin.x)+(_pinchUI_bottom.frame.size.width/2), touchLoc.y);
            _pinchUI_bottom.center = touchLocY;

            // If outside of image, stop
            if (touchLocY.y > imageHeight.y) {
                _pinchUI_bottom.center = imageHeight;
            }
            else {
                pixelsFromTop = touchLoc.y;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This should fix it.